# How to run a Python script not as '~$ python myscript.py' but as a single command '~$ myscript'?

Tags: command-line, scripts, python

I have a Python script which takes command line arguments.

When I want to run the script I have to navigate to its directory and run:

```
python myscript.py [arguments]
```

How can I run it like:

```
myscript [arguments]
```

Do I have to create a package? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your script so your first line is a shebang pointing to the desired interpreter's executable path.

First, find where the `python` executable is, with `which python`.

Then, in your script's first line, add

```
#!/path/to/python
```

Then run

```
mkdir $HOME/bin
```

And put your script there.

That should do it!

Comment: This worked after I changed the name of 'myscript.py' to just 'myscript'.

Comment: The best way to do this is #!/usr/bin/env python . this way you can change python version easily and you script can  adjust to more system layouts

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure `myscript.py` is executable by doing `chmod +x myscript.py`. Second, ensure that the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python` appears as the first line of `myscript.py`. You then execute the script using `./myscript.py [arguments]`.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

to the first line of your script.  This presumes that you have python installed and runnable from /usr/bin, and that the current directory (.) is in your PATH environment variable (not the default,but you can change it in your home .profile  file).